# Detect collision of sprite created TimeHandler

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, physics, game-physics

I am using a timehandler to generate  sprites in Andengine.

Now I want detect collision between that sprites and other sprites in same Scene.

I tried using the code below but it did not work as expected.

Is there is another  way to detect collision?

```
    //method to create sprite

public void add()

    {
        mFaceCount++;
        Random rand = new Random();
            int x = (int) CAMERA_WIDTH + mb1.getWidth();
        int minY = mb1.getHeight();
        int maxY = (int) (CAMERA_HEIGHT/2 - mb1
            .getHeight());
        int rangeY = maxY + minY;
       // int y = rand.nextInt(280) + 320;
        int y=rand.nextInt(350-280) + 280;

        int minDuration = 2;
        int maxDuration = 3;
        int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
        int actualDuration = rand.nextInt(rangeDuration) + minDuration;

        if(this.mFaceCount%2==0)
        {
            targetSprite =new Sprite(x,y,mb4.clone());
            mScene.attachChild(b1);
            B1= PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, b1, BodyType.KinematicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);

        }
        else  if(this.mFaceCount%3==0)
        {
            targetSprite =new Sprite(x,y,mb2.clone());
            mScene.attachChild(b1);
            B1= PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, b1, BodyType.KinematicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);

        }
        B1.setLinearVelocity(-5, 0);
          mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(b1, B1, true, false)
            {
              @Override
               public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed)
            {
                super.onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);
            }
         });


}


// time handler


private void createSpriteSpawnTimeHandler(){
        TimerHandler spriteTimerHandler;
        float mEffectSpawnDelay = 2f;
        spriteTimerHandler = new TimerHandler(mEffectSpawnDelay,true,new ITimerCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            add();
       }
        });
        getEngine().registerUpdateHandler(spriteTimerHandler);
    }



//update handler to detect collision


IUpdateHandler updateHandler = new IUpdateHandler()
    {

        @Override
        public void reset() { }


        @Override
        public void onUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed) 
        {




             if (hanger.collidesWith(targetSprite))
             {  
                    System.out.println("Collision);
                    ;
             }


        }
};
```

Comment: "I tried but not worked" Good, you're showing some effort toward the resolution of the problem, but we need to see what you tried because we can't otherwise tell you what are the OTHER ways.

Comment: see http://sscce.org/ to learn how to post code related to your question

Comment: thnks...But do u know solution about this question?

Comment: No, sorry. But i can help you to get more and better answers, at least.

Answer (score 1):

First assign Different fixtures based on type of bodies.
Then implement contact listener for your world as follows:

```
    CustomContactListener customContact = new CustomContactListener(bxWorld);
            bxWorld.setContactListener(customContact); 




public class CustomContactListener implements ContactListener{
    World bxWorld;
    UserData userDataA, userDataB;
    Body bodyA, bodyB;
    GamePlayLayer gameScene;

    Fixture fixtureA, fixtureB;
    public boolean isFirstCollision;
    public  ArrayList<Body> menHitList;

    public CustomContactListener(World bxWorld) {
        bxWorld.setContactListener(this);
        this.bxWorld = bxWorld;
        this.gameScene = GamePlayLayer.gameScene;
        this.menHitList = new ArrayList<Body>();
    }

    @Override
    public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
        fixtureA = contact.getFixtureA();
        fixtureB = contact.getFixtureB();

        bodyA  = fixtureA.getBody();
        bodyB  = fixtureB.getBody();

        userDataA = (UserData) bodyA.getUserData();
        userDataB = (UserData) bodyB.getUserData();
    }

    @Override
    public void endContact(Contact arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void postSolve(Contact arg0, ContactImpulse arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold arg1) {
        Vector2[] contactVector = contact.getWorldManifold().getPoints();

        ObjectType objectTypeA = userDataA.getObjectType();
        ObjectType objectTypeB = userDataB.getObjectType();


        if((objectTypeA == ObjectType.ITEM_THROWN ) && objectTypeB == ObjectType.BOUNDARY_BOTTOM_DOWN ){

            // to remove multiple collisions
            // to prevent projectile mirvs from scheduler


        }else if(objectTypeA == ObjectType.BOUNDARY_BOTTOM_DOWN && objectTypeB == ObjectType.ITEM_THROWN ){


        }       


    }


}
```

You can implement what ever collision you want in this